# Can't connect remotely to database on SQL Server 2005

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am new to managing servers but I have just been given full access to set up an MS SQL Database on win server 2003. I have created a Database successfully and can connect locally (via remote desktop server)

Problem is I can't connect to the database from my personal computer (remotely, via ms sql server management studio). I have followed several tutorials such as: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Also, allow remote connections is enabled in sql and windows firewall is disabled.

The error I am receiving is:

> Cannot connect to 'servername'
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: 53)

Any help will be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There may be other firewalls between the boxes. But first check that SQL server is configured to listen for network connections. by default (for security) it will not accept network connections.

Have you configured the network to accept TCP/IP or named pipe connections? And verified that it is listening on those connections?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277 How to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections

Answer (score 0):

Can you "ping" the destination server?, can you "telnet" to sql on the destination server?

```
telnet <servername> 1433
```